# Saving String as UUID in postgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, uuid

I am stuck on 1 problem. In my project getters and setters are of type STRING and SQL definition for corresponding column is UniqueIdentifier which works fine. for Example:

```
@Column(name="name")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

But when we started support for PostgreSQL DB we migrated all the tables with the definition UUID as column type where it throws error that

*I am trying to save character varying as UUID either cast it or change the column type.*

Error:

**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "uid" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.**

I know the solution that I have to change my getters/setters to java.util.UUID type but we can't take this solution as it will require all getters and setters changes in whole workspace.

I tried the solution:
[HERE](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/)
 which says that I can save UUID as String(DB Column type) but not explain how to save String as UUID(DB Column type)

I have tried this in Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="emptest4")
public class Employee {

@Id
@Column(name="uid", columnDefinition = "UUID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String uid;
```

and in Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

SO that it creates table automatically. I observed that the table created was like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.emptest4
(
uid uuid NOT NULL,
name character varying(255),
CONSTRAINT emptest4_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
```

but the error was same :(.

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Can you specify version of Hibernate?

Comment: Its the Hibernate 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 5 is JPA 2.1 compatible. You can use @AttributeConvertor for your first sample. Nice article about it: [How to implement a Converter?](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/)

But is does not work for @Id column (your second sample). In this case most reasonable way (imho) is add additional getter/setter methods with transforming between string <-> uuid, and use UUID as ID datatype

PS

My idea:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="emptest4")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name="uid", columnDefinition = "UUID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID originalUid;

    public String getUid(){
        return ..// convert originalUid to string
    } 

    public void setUid(String id){
        originalUid =  ..// convert id to originalUid
    } 

    //Getter and Setter for originalUid value
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't understand solution very well but have tried something else but again error is thrown. Tried 

    private UUID uid;
 
 /*@Id
 @Column(name="uid")
 private UUID uid;*/

 public String getUid() {
  return uid.toString();
 }
 public void setUid(String uid) {
  this.uid = UUID.fromString(uid);
 }

but error while I added UUID as type in HBM.xml

Comment: I modify my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Actually that is what I have written in comment above.

SETTER
`public void setUid(String uid) { this.uid = UUID.fromString(uid); }`

GETTER
`public String getUid() { return uid.toString(); }`

but that is giving problem in XML shows that getId is returning NULL.

Comment: And If I try to put a code that converts as desired, will be called multiple times. Will that be time consuming? I understand that manually things can be converted.

Comment: You should not change default getter / setter methods for hibernate field.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string value into UUID as below :

```
import java.util.UUID 
val ID =  UUID.fromString(row.getString(uid))
```

You can then pass the ID value and it would work.